# Trying to make if, elseif, else statement for time and when to eat using military clock format

Tags: php, if-statement, time

Whenever I put in the number 12 or 16, for example, it will not say "It's time for lunch" or "It's time for dinner." It will always say "It's time for breakfast"

I've tried putting quotes around the numbers, I've tried looking at my greater than, less than, etc. signs, and it looks like that is not the problem i think..

```
    <?php

    $time = 4;

   if(($time >= 4) || ($time <= 11))
   {
   echo "It's time for breakfast";
   } 
   elseif(($time >= 12) || ($time <= 15))
   {
   echo "It's time for lunch";
   }
   else 
   {
   echo "It's time for dinner";
   }
   ?>
```

I want it to run so when I make 4 - 11 in $time it will echo "It's time for breakfast." I want from 12 - 15 in $time to echo "It's time for lunch." All other numbers should print It's time for dinner.

Comment: Of course you will be getting an output `It's time for breakfast` because the value of `$time` variable is set statically to `4` which is true on your first condition. Try to replace `$time` to `$test = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$time= (new DateTime($test))->format("H");` just to get your current date and time and extract only time on a `24-hour` format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your conditions. Right now, you're asking:

"If the time is greater than or equal to 4 OR time is less than or equal to 15..."

It will always be true if the time is greater than or equal to 4 OR less than or equal to 15 so the `else if` will never be reached. You must change to AND so both conditions must be met to stay in the `if` block.

```
<?php

$time = 16;

if(($time >= 4) && ($time <= 11))
{
    echo "It's time for breakfast";
}
elseif(($time >= 12) && ($time <= 15))
{
    echo "It's time for lunch";
}
else
{
    echo "It's time for dinner";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to get lost in many `if ifelse else` conditions. A simple way would I like to think about them is to think of them systematically, like this for example:

```
$time = 4;

if ( $time >= 15 || $time < 4 ) {
    echo "It's time for dinner";
} elseif( $time >= 12 ) {
    echo "It's time for lunch";
} elseif ( $time >= 4 ) {
    echo "It's time for breakfast";
}
```